# How do I decide the height and scrolling position of window in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to grab the height of the window and the scrolling offset in jQuery, but I haven't had any luck finding this in the jQuery docs or Google. I'm 90% certain there's a way to access height and scrollTop for an element (presumably including the window), but I just can't find the specific. I am stuck on code below

```
var height = $(window).height();
var scrollTop =$(window).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure what the jQuery Approved™ way of doing this would be, but in plain JavaScript:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must understand the basic difference between $(window) and $(document).

`$(window)` refers to the viewport

`$(document)` refers to the actual html document

So in your case you'd use `$(document).scrollTop();` for the scroll distance and depending on needs (actual viewport height or document height) either `$(document).height()` or `$(window).height()`

Edit: Check out http://api.jquery.com/height/ and http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/